# pow(a,e,n) doesn't work for input pow(1,3,3)

Tags: python, pow, sage

why do I get this error message, when I'm using these parameters(pow(1,3,3)) ?:

```
sage: pow(1,3,3)                                    
3
3/2
3/2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/kai/<ipython console> in <module>()

/home/kai/<ipython console> in pow(a, e, n)

/usr/lib/sagemath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/rings/rational.so in sage.rings.rational.Rational.__mod__ (sage/rings/rational.c:19891)()

/usr/lib/sagemath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/rings/integer.so in sage.rings.integer.Integer.inverse_mod (sage/rings/integer.c:32726)()

ZeroDivisionError: Inverse does not exist.
```

pow():

```
def pow(a,e,n):
....:     num = 1
....:     while e >= 1:
....:         print(e)
....:         if (e%2) == 1:
....:             num = (num*a) % n  
....:         e = e/2
....:         print(e)
....:         a = (a*a) % n
....:     return num
....:
```

Comment: This function works fine with those parameters for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modular exponentiation by squaring algorithm you implemented should use integers.

`e = e/2` returns a Rational `3/2`.

You should convert this to an integer `e = (e/2).floor()`.

Comment: Thank you, that one modification did it.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = (a*a) % n
```

a = 1*1 % 1
a -> 0
what means taht n your case is 0, so here

```
num = (num*a) % n
```

You will have 0 % 3.

edit:
Is it possible to do 3/2 % 3 in python?

Comment: @fiso It was not very clear in the beginning, but the OP uses [sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)